# How to solve Fatal error in php

Tags: php, fatal-error

While running the codes on local host it is showing an error of--

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in 
C:\wamp\www\crawler_based_search_engine\ajax_requests.php on line 130
```

**Call Stack**

```
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0151  162928  {main}( )   ..\ajax_requests.php:0
```

**the codes from line 130 and beyond is as follows**

```
            $html = file_get_html($file_name);
            // Find all links 
            foreach($html->find('a') as $element) //--this is line no 130
            {
                $url = $element->href;
                $index = strpos($url,'q=https://');
                if($index > 0)
                {
                    $index2 = strpos($url,'webcache');
                    if($index2 === false)
                    {
                        $index2 = strpos($url,'sa=U');
                        $url = substr($element->href,$index+2,$index2-$index-3);
                        echo "<a href='$url'>$url</a>";
                        echo '<hr/>';
                    }
                }
            }
```

because of this error my program is not fetching the links from the google

Comment: what does  `$html` get.print out it.

Comment: print '<pre>';print_r($html); first

Comment: This means `file_get_html()` is getting an error, so it's returning `false`. This will happen if the HTML is invalid, also if it's too large.

Comment: **file_get_html()**  function doesnt exist. use file_get_contents() instead ,thats y you are getting this error..

Comment: @CodingHorror If that were the case, the error would say "call to undefined function". The first step in debugging is reading the sodding error message.